# Is set topology difference a topology with trivial topology amended

Tags: general-topology

Given a finite set $X$, there can be many topologies define on it.

And by definition, the trivial topology $T_0 = \{\emptyset, X \}$ is always a subset of all topologies. Suppose there are two different topologies $T_i, T_j$ on $X$.

Would the $(T_i \setminus T_j) \cup T_0$ be a valid topology on $X$ ?

Comment: Try messing around with low cardinality topologies, attempting to create a topology $T_j$ that has a critical open set for $T_i$ (i.e. that if you remove the open set $T_i$ no longer satisfies the union or intersection axiom).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $X = \{ a,b,c \}$, $\mathscr T_1 = \{\emptyset,\{b\}, \{a,b\},\{b,c\},X\}$, and $\mathscr T_2 = \{ \emptyset, \{b\}, X\}$. Then $\left( \mathscr T_1 \setminus \mathscr T_2 \right) \cup \{\emptyset,X\}$ is not a toplogy on $X$.

Answer (score 2):

Not at all. Consider $X = \{ 1,2, 3 \}$ and let $T_1 = P(X)$ (every set is open) and $T_2 = \{ \varnothing, \{3\}, X \}$ Then $(T_1 -T_2) \cup T_0$ is not a topology because { 1,3 } and { 2, 3} are open sets but their intersection is not openz